# ColdFusion Dynamic Text Area

Tags: mysql, coldfusion

Having a little problem here. I'm working on a project and a client needs the functionality to be able to update/chose to publish reviews from their control panel to their live site.

I've got the code deleting records from the database just fine, but I'm having trouble targeting the specific text area from the dynamically populated list (I hope that makes sense).

I'm setting the ID of the text area to the ReviewID in the database, so that the right record would be updated on submit. This is the code I have set up on the textarea

```
<textarea rows="5" style="width: 800px;" id="
    <cfloop query='rsGetName'>
        <cfif #rsGetTestimonials.ClientID# EQ #rsGetName.ClientID#>
            #rsGetTestimonials.ReviewID#
        </cfif>
    </cfloop>">
    #rsGetTestimonials.cTestimonial#
</textarea>
```

So the ID of the text area is a dynamic integer.

How do I target this so that it updates the right record in the database? My submit button looks like this -

```
<a href="testimonials-view.cfm?rID=#ReviewID#" title="Update this testimonial">
   <img src="images/buttonSaveContinue.gif" border="0" />
</a>
```

so it posts back to the same page and appends the Review ID on the end of the URL, which I'm trying to use to get it to update the right database record.

My update query looks like this. The logic of what I'm trying to do is pretty evident in this.

```
<cfif IsDefined('URL.rID')>
    <cfquery datasource="#Request.dsn#">
        UPDATE clientreview 
        SET cTestimonial = #FORM.rsGetTestimonials.ReviewID#
        WHERE 
            ReviewID = #URL.rID#
    </cfquery>
</cfif>
```

Any help on this one would be greatly appreciated!

If this doesn't make as much sense as I hope it does, then let me know and I'll try to explain a little more.

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: what happens when this code runs? does the wrong record get updated? does the wrong text area content get applied?

Comment: Element RSGETTESTIMONIALS.REVIEWID is undefined in FORM.

Because the loop is assigning it a numerical value in the <cfoutput>, id becomes "8" or "142" etc. Which ColdFusion wont parse as its looking for rsGetTestimonials.ReviewID, which doesnt exist. I just had an idea though.

Comment: i don't think the form is being submitted - if you are using a hyperlink it will simply be loading the url

Comment: It will be submitted. I parse the reviewID to the URL, then when the page reloads it runs the query to update the clientreview database, it just doesnt know which row to update. And my problem is, I dont know how to tell it which row to update without hardcoding in the id.

Comment: i'm not really following your approach, however if the problem boils down to how to refer to a dynamically named field you can use a different notation style. Try `form.rsGetTestimonials[url.rID]`

Comment: Thats sort of it.

I have a text field. I'm dynamically naming it. How do I get the UPDATE query to SET cTestimonial equal to that dynamically named text field?

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem lies in that your not naming the text area, give it a fixed or dynamic name then reference that name in your update.

Comment: Indeed. Variables in the FORM scope are built on element `name` not `id`.